# Using InfoPath inBrowser forms, create reports from captured data, and present those reports back in SharePoint

Tags: infopath, bcs, sql-server, reporting-services, database

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and I have access to InfoPath and BCS services.

I’m looking to use InfoPath forms that are accessed IN-BROWSER through SharePoint to capture data, and use that data to generate reports.

For the moment, I’m storing all the captured data within SharePoint Lists but I need more powerful relational ability than can be provided through Lists.

I have three requirements:

1. The data should be stored in a Database.
2. I need to be able to create printable reports based on this data.
3. The reports should be accessible through the SharePoint site.

At a high level what would  I need to accomplish this? I understand that I may need to use BCS, SQL Server, and Reporting Services, but I don’t know how to proceed after that. Also, please note I'm working in a Corporate IT environment.